# Use AS3 to open an swf. in a browser without the browser toolbar (forward / back buttons)

Tags: actionscript-3, internet-explorer-8, flash

I have developed a very large swf. that will only be accessed in-house. There are over 100 scenes & 10000 frames (I had no idea the project would grow this large). I have developed a navigation system within the swf., but I have found that many users are clicking the forward / back buttons in the browser toolbar (IE8). This is a big issue for me, because the user then has no way to return to the location in the swf. that they were in before hitting the back button. Is there a way to code into the swf. using AS3 to ensure that the browser toolbar is disabled?

Comment: You can open your swf in a popup without toolbar, or using a new page where page history is empty, or in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Thank you, akomzo. Opening the swf. in a popup without a toolbar is what I'm trying to do. How can I make sure that anyone clicking on the link to the swf. gets a popup instead of a standard browser window?

Comment: Don't worry about that, just put parameters that you want and let the browser do the rest, but sometimes popups are blocked by some plugins or the browser it self. Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for more details about how to use `window.open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the parts of the user interface that the users are using a lot is a very bad idea.

Instead, simply use the browser buttons for navigation.

[SWFAddress let's you do that](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/)

You can have deep linking, too. (allows users to send a link of where they are to other people)

Take a look at this answer:
[How to make the browser back button work for a Flash-based Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828396/how-to-make-the-browser-back-button-work-for-a-flash-based-website)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. SWFAddress is a great solution. Many Thanks!